# Using solve_ivp in a delayed feedback control system

Tags: python, scipy, ode, numerical-integration

I'm trying to replicate some simulations from an [academic paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960077915001642) using solve_ivp to solve the following ODE:

[Delayed feedback control system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E99QX.png)

I noticed that there are two types of variables, the normal "x" and "x(t)", I know it's because of the time delay but I'm not sure how to implement the second one using "solve_ivp". This is my code without the time-delayed force:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
a = 0.6
b = -1.1
c = 0.45

A = 12.8
B = 19.1

t_in=0
t_fin=100

tspam = [t_in,t_fin]
t=np.linspace(t_in,t_fin,10000)


vall0 = [0.001, 0.001, 0.001]
def fun (t, Vall):
  x,y,z = Vall 
  X = A*(y-(a*x)-(b*x**2)-(c*x**3)) #Here is where I'm supposed to add the time-delayed force
  Y = x-y+z
  Z = -B*y
  return [X,Y,Z]



sol = solve_ivp(fun, tspam, vall0, t_eval=t)
```

I've tried to look online for a solution but most of the time people recommend to use the [jitcdde library](https://jitcdde.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) but I don't really know how to combine those two types of variables ("x" and "x(t)").

Comment: All the `x`s in that equation are the same and are functions of time. It's only in that last, time-delayed force term where they distinguish `x` being evaluated at `t` to `x` being evaluated at `t-tau`.